# Sort dict of dict by two values of sub dicts

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

test_dict = {'test1':{'key1': 'dog', 'key2': 'dennis', 'key3': 'bbb'},
             'test2':{'key1': 'apple', 'key2': 'arthur', 'key3': 'fff'},
             'test3':{'key1': 'bear', 'key2': 'bernard', 'key3': 'xxx'},
             'test4':{'key1': 'elephant', 'key2': 'eric', 'key3': 'rrr'},
             'test5':{'key1': 'cat', 'key2': 'charlie', 'key3': 'lll'}
             }


sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(test_dict.items(), key=lambda i: i[1]['key1'][1]['key3']))

for key, value in sorted_dict.items():
    print(key, value)
```

This generates the error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

However if I amend as so:

```
sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(test_dict.items(), key=lambda i: i[1]['key1']))
```

...it will sort the sub dicts in order successfully by key1 only. However, I want to sort by key1 and key3. What do I need to change?

Comment: Just change your lambda to `lambda i: (i[1]['key1'], i[1]['key3'])`. However, in your test-case, that doesn't change the order from when you're just sorting by `key1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your snippet, notice this line:

```py
sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(test_dict.items(), key=lambda i: i[1]['key1'][1]['key3']))
```

Here, `test_dict.items()` returns a `dict_item` object containing a list of tuples of key-value pairs. In your case, the keys are strings and the values are dicts. So in the lambda expression, when you select `i[1]['key1']` you're already getting the string value attached to that key. So when you're trying to access `i[1]['key1'][1]['key3']`, you're trying to access `key3` value from a single character. Hence the `TypeError`.

The fix is easy, the lamda expression in `sorted` can return multiple values and they'll be used to sort your target dict.

```
sorted_dict = OrderedDict(
    sorted(test_dict.items(), key=lambda i: (i[1]["key1"], i[1]["key3"]))
)
```

Also, if you're using Python 3.7 and up, you don't actually need the `OrderedDict` as the native dictionary retains the order of the keys. This is also valid:

```
sorted_dict = dict(sorted(test_dict.items(), key=lambda i: (i[1]["key1"], i[1]["key3"])))
```

It'll print the following:

```
test2 {'key1': 'apple', 'key2': 'arthur', 'key3': 'fff'}
test3 {'key1': 'bear', 'key2': 'bernard', 'key3': 'xxx'}
test5 {'key1': 'cat', 'key2': 'charlie', 'key3': 'lll'}
test1 {'key1': 'dog', 'key2': 'dennis', 'key3': 'bbb'}
test4 {'key1': 'elephant', 'key2': 'eric', 'key3': 'rrr'}
```

Answer (score 1):

This method you can sort a list by several attributes

> Sorting by two keys uses two methods of comparison to sort elements in a collection

```
sorted_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(test_dict.items(),key=lambda i:(i[1]["key1"],i[1]["key3"])))

for key, value in sorted_dict.items():
    print(key, value)
```

output :

```
test2 {'key1': 'apple', 'key2': 'arthur', 'key3': 'fff'}
test3 {'key1': 'bear', 'key2': 'bernard', 'key3': 'xxx'}
test5 {'key1': 'cat', 'key2': 'charlie', 'key3': 'lll'}
test1 {'key1': 'dog', 'key2': 'dennis', 'key3': 'bbb'}
test4 {'key1': 'elephant', 'key2': 'eric', 'key3': 'rrr'}
```